# Excel add-in is not activating

Tags: excel, add-in

I have created an excel add-in for office 2007. From code this is working.

Now i am creating setup for it.

I have set, following settings

File System -> primary output of ExcelPublisherAddin2007, and all dlls.

Registry ->
 HKEY_Current_User > Software > Microsoft > Office > Excel > Addins > ExcelPublisherAddin2007

```
 CommandLineSafe       1
 Description           ExcelPublisherAddIn2007 -- an addin created with VSTO technology
 FriendlyName          ExcelPublisherAddIn2007
 LoadBehavior          3
 Manifest              [TARGETDIR]ExcelPublisherAddIn2007.dll.manifest
 Version               1.0.1
```

Custom Actions ->
     INstall

```
    Primary output from CGN.DataCast.DataCastTieredLibrary.ExcelPublisherAddIn.SetSecurity (Active)
```

CustomeData Action

```
/assemblyName="ExcelPublisherAddIn2007.dll" /targetDir="[TARGETDIR]\"     /solutionCodeGroupName="ExcelPublisherAddIn2007" /solutionCodeGroupDescription="Code group for ExcelPublisherAddIn2007" /assemblyCodeGroupName="ExcelPublisherAddIn2007" /assemblyCodeGroupDescription="Code group for ExcelPublisherAddIn2007" /allUsers=[ALLUSERS]
```

Same code on Commit, Rollback and Uninstall

Launch Condition > Search Target Machine

```
 Search for Office 2010 Shared PIA  ->  Component Id - {64E2917E-AA13-4CA4-BFFE-EA6EDA3AFCB4}, Property - HASSHAREDPIA

 Search for Office 2010 VSTO Runtime -> Property - OFFICERUNTIME
 RegKey - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4
 Root - vsdrrHKLM
 Value - Version

 Search for VSTO 2010 Runtime -> Property - VSTORUNTIMEREDIST
  RegKey - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4R
  Root - vsdrrHKLM
  Value - Version
```

Launch Condition ->

```
 .NET Framework -> INstall Url - http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=131000
  Messate - [VSDNETMSG]
  Version - .NET Framework 3.5 Client Profile
```

Verify Office 2010 Shared PIA availability
      Condition - HASSHAREDPIA

Verify VSTO 2010 Runtime availability
      Condition - VSTORUNTIMEREDIST>="10.0.30319" OR OFFICERUNTIME>=”10.0.21022”

Now, when i am installing it, this is registering in to Inactive Applications.
   [image: Print Short]
I am activating it by selecting Com Object in "Manage" dropdown and selecting it.

But still this is not going to Activated Application list.

I have also registered installed location in to Trusted Location.

Please help.

Comment: why no one is responding?